# How to get a remote-file's mtime before downloading it in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, file, download

I have the below code, which simply downloads a file and saves it. I want to run it every 30 seconds and check if the remote-file's mtime has changed and download it if it has.
I'll be creating a thread which sleeps 30seconds after every iteration of an endless loop for that purpose, but; how do I check a remote file's mtime without downloading it?

```
Net::HTTP.start($xmlServerHostname) { |http|
                resp = http.get($xmlServerPath+"levels.xml")
                open("levels.xml", "w") { |file|
                    file.write(resp.body)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you do your `http.get` do an [http.head](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M000682) which requests just the headers without downloading the body (i.e. the file contents) then check if the value of the Last Modified header has changed.

e.g.

```
resp = http.head(($xmlServerPath+"levels.xml")
last_modified = resp['last-modified']
if last_modified != previous_last_modified
  # file has changed
end
```

Comment: Can I do both http.head and http.get in the same HTTP.start block?

Comment: I've just tried it here and doing both in the same start block seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to send the [If-Modified-Since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) header with a correctly formatted date.

If the server supports it, it can answer just with a [304 Not Modified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) status (without any content) or the full content if the file has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

The [official `Net::HTTP` 2.6.5 docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers) have a concrete example of `If-Modified-Since` which was mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509202/895245

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/cached_response')
file = File.stat 'cached_response'

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

open 'cached_response', 'w' do |io|
  io.write res.body
end if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

Here is a full script that actually runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'time'

uri = URI('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Illumina_iSeq_100_flow_cell_top.jpg/451px-Illumina_iSeq_100_flow_cell_top.jpg')
file_path = 'cached_response'
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
if File.file?(file_path)
  req['If-Modified-Since'] = File.stat(file_path).mtime.rfc2822
end
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
if res.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
  File.open(file_path, 'w') {|io|
    io.write res.body
  }
end
```

but TODO it is updating the file every time, even though Wikimedia seems to interpret `If-Modified-Since`: https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_caching